# Querying a data with Django ORM to return a specific data that belongs to a user

Tags: python, django, database, django-rest-framework, backend

so I'm trying to build a Ledger App. When new users sign-ups, they create a new Business account that is linked to them (ForeignKey). Here is my model:

```
User = get_user_model()

class Business_Account(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
business_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Type_of_service = models.CharField(choices=SERVICE_CATEGORIES, max_length=50)
business_email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=254)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Business_Account"
    verbose_name_plural = "Business_Accounts"

def __str__(self):
    return self.business_name
```

Now, I want to make a get request view that can query and returns a business account that belongs to a particular user. My current view just returns all the business accounts available in the database irrespective of which user is login. Here is my view:

```
class AddBusinessAcctView(APIView):
def get_object(self):
    try:
        return Business_Account.objects.all()
    except:
        raise status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND

def get(self,request):
    queryset = self.get_object()
    serializer = BusinessAcctSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Now, How can I query business accounts that belong to a particular user?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it. It is something similar to the above answer.

```
queryset = Business_Account.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'd have [authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/) and a logged-in user that you were trying to retrieve information for.  Assuming you're going to do this, that user is available in the `request` object.

```py
Business_Account.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

But in general, you can just do:

```py
user = User.objects.get(username='john')
Business_Account.objects.get(user=request.user)

# or
Business_Account.objects.get(user_id=123456)
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this but I still got an error. But what worked for me was to change the 'object.get()' to 'object.filter()'